# Maximal set of string-covering substring terms

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy

I want to calculate the largest covering of a string from many sets of substrings.

All strings in this problem are lowercased, and contain no whitespace or unicode strangeness.

So, given a string: `abcdef`, and two groups of strings: `['abc', 'bc'], ['abc', 'd']`, the second group (`['abc', 'd']`) covers more of the original string. Order matters for exact matches, so the term group `['fe', 'cba']` would not match the original string.

I have a large collection of strings, and a large collection of terms-groups. So I would like a bit faster implementation if possible.

I've tried the following in Python for an example. I've used Pandas and Numpy because I thought it may speed it up a bit. I'm also running into an over-counting problem as you'll see below.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_strings = pd.Series(['foobar', 'foofoobar0', 'apple'])

term_sets = pd.Series([['foo', 'ba'], ['foo', 'of'], ['app', 'ppl'], ['apple'], ['zzz', 'zzapp']])


# For each string, calculate best proportion of coverage:
# Try 1: Create a function for each string.
def calc_coverage(mystr, term_sets):
    
    # Total length of string
    total_chars = len(mystr)

    # For each term set, sum up length of any match. Problem: this over counts when matches overlap.
    total_coverage = term_sets.apply(lambda x: np.sum([len(term) if re.search(term, mystr) else 0 for term in x]))

    # Fraction of String covered. Note the above over-counting can result in fractions > 1.0.
    coverage_proportion = total_coverage/total_chars

    return coverage_proportion.argmax(), coverage_proportion.max()


my_strings.apply(lambda x: calc_coverage(x, term_sets))
```

This results in:

```
0    (0, 0.8333333333333334)
1                   (0, 0.5)
2                   (2, 1.2)
```

Which presents some problems. The biggest problem I see is that over-lapping terms are being counted up separately, which results in the `1.2` or 120% coverage.

I think the ideal output would be:

```
0    (0, 0.8333333333333334)
1                   (0, 0.8)
2                   (3, 1.0)
```

I think I can write a double for loop and brute force it. But this problem feels like there's a more optimal solution. Or a small change on what I've done so far to get it to work.

> Note: If there is a tie- returning the first is fine. I'm not too interested in returning all best matches.

Comment: in `['abc', 'bc']` do you consider that the two `bc` overlap?, "*I've used Pandas and Numpy because I thought it may speed it up a bit.*" -> not if you use `apply`, it's actually often slower that pure python

Comment: Yes, overlaps are the big problem I'm trying to fix. I want to _not_ count overlaps multiple times.

I didn't know about the `apply` vs basic-python. I'll see what I can do there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is not optimized but let's start fixing the results. I believe you have two issues: one is the over-counting in `apple`; the other is the under-counting in `foofoobar0`.

Solving the second issue when the term set is composed of two non-overlapping terms (or just one term), is easy:

```
sum([s.count(t)*len(t) for t in ts])
```

will do the job.

Similarly, when we have two overlapping terms, we will just take the "best" one:

```
max([s.count(t)*len(t) for t in ts])
```

So we are left with the problem of recognizing when the two terms overlap. I don't even consider term sets with more than two terms, because the solution will already be painfully slow with two :(

Let's define a function to test for overlapping:

```
def terms_overlap(s, ts):
    if ts[0] not in s or ts[1] not in s:
        return False
    start = 0
    while (pos_0 := s.find(ts[0], start)) > -1:
        if (pos_1 := s.find(ts[1], pos_0)) > -1:
            if pos_0 <= pos_1 < (pos_0 + len(ts[0]) - 1):
                return True
        start += pos_0 + len(ts[0])
    start = 0
    while (pos_1 := s.find(ts[1], start)) > -1:
        if (pos_0 := s.find(ts[0], pos_1)) > -1:
            if pos_1 <= pos_0 < (pos_1 + len(ts[1]) - 1):
                return True
        start += pos_1 + len(ts[1])
    return False
```

With that function ready we can finally do:

```
def calc_coverage(strings, tsets):
    for xs, s in enumerate(strings):
        best_cover = 0
        best_ts = 0
        for xts, ts in enumerate(tsets):
            if len(ts) == 1:
                cover = s.count(ts[0])*len(ts[0])
            elif len(ts) == 2:
                if terms_overlap(s, ts):
                    cover = max([s.count(t)*len(t) for t in ts])
                else:
                    cover = sum([s.count(t)*len(t) for t in ts])
            else:
                raise ValueError('Cannot handle term sets of more than two terms')
            if cover > best_cover:
                best_cover = cover
                best_ts = xts
        print(f'{xs}: {s:15} {best_cover:2d} / {len(s):2d} = {best_cover/len(s):8.3f} ({best_ts}: {tsets[best_ts]})')

>>> calc_coverage(my_strings, term_sets)
0: foobar           5 /  6 =    0.833 (0: ['foo', 'ba'])
1: foofoobar0       8 / 10 =    0.800 (0: ['foo', 'ba'])
2: apple            5 /  5 =    1.000 (3: ['apple'])
```